# Get attribute during .on event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have 10 links like this:  `<a href="#" data-test="test" class="testclass"></a>`
and on function. Like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".testclass", function () {
        alert($(this).attr('data-test'));
    });
```

I cannot understand how can I get data-test attribute for a specific a tag in this case. `$(this)` returns `document` object and not `a`

Comment: `$(this).data('test')` should work as well.

Comment: it work http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/TZtFA/ what is your jquery version ?

Comment: If `this` for some strange reason does'nt work (it should), try `event.target` instead.

Comment: The code you posted [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/vBSTy/). Post your real code.

Answer (score -1):

You have to bind the listener to the anchor, not the document:

```
$('a.testclass').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).data('test'));
})
```

And [data function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is the right way to get data attached to a DOM element.

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the object on which the listener was attached, in your case `document` not a. Felix's answer is correct because the listener will be attached to the `a.testclass` element.

Comment: .on with a second parameter will mean .live of the parameter inside the selector

Comment: OP is using delegated version of `on()`. Your version won't work for future elements. OP version should work fine and you can certainly bind to `document`